# different result in pycharm and python console using slicing step

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

1/ for this Python3.5 code

```
a=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
a[::-1]
print(a)
```

python IDE output (the expected result):

```
[8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

Pycharm output (a wrong result):

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

I find it confusing to get different result depending on the console. Why is it different?

2/ Idem for this one:

```
x = "Hello World !"
x[6:2:-1]
print(x)
```

python output:

```
'W ol'
```

Pycharm output:

```
Hello World !
```

Comment: The console is definitely producing the right output. Which version of PyCharm are you running?

Comment: The statement ``a[::-1]`` DOESN'T DO ANYTHING - it throws away the reversed string.  You'd have to do ``a = a[::-1]`` to get your expected results.

Comment: @jasonharper Thank you very much for your reply. I understand now. (@DrZoo : I'm using pycharm 2016.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with jasonharper here, what PyCharm shows you is correct, since you do not actually change a.

The only behaviour where you would get this is in an interactive python session. So if you call `python` in your console, run `a=[1,2,3,4]`, enter and then `a[::-1]` you will get the result of that computation in the console. If you then run `a` again you will see that a did not change afterall.

Answer (score 0):

Let's take your second example

Strings are immutable. The python console just spits out the result of the slice command immediately. `x` is never changed, so `print(x)` should be the same in all python environments in that case.

PyCharm, however, only outputs the `print` commands because the entire script is interpreted, not line-by-line.